# Why Don't my Parameters get Passed in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So, I'm really new to Ruby on Rails and the whole thing still sounds like Chinese to me. Excuse me if this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to make a new button on my app that lets me copy things.

On my form I have:

```
%span.btn.btn-mini.btn-inverse= link_to copy_image, copy_campaign_signal_processor_item_path(@campaign, @processor, item) ,data: { toggle:"modal",target: "#myModal"}, remote: true
```

That works fine and creates the button for me. Then, in routes.rb, I have:

```
resources :signal_processors, exclude: [:index, :new, :create], controller: 'processors' do

        member do
          get :modify, :action => :edit, :force_schema_update => true
        end

        resources :items do
          member do
            get :copy
          end
        end
```

Finally, in the items_controller.rb, I have:

```
  def copy
    @overlay_title = "Copy #{@processor.item_name}"
    @processor.properties.each do |property|
      unless @item.property_values.collect{|a| a.property_id}.index(property.id)
        @item.property_values << SignalProcessor::PropertyValue.new(property: property)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

The problem is that for some reason `item` doesn't seem to get passed to the `copy` function in items_controller.rb, so every time I click the copy button, I get the error:

`undefined method`property_values' for nil:NilClass`

for the line:

`unless @item.property_values.collect{|a| a.property_id}.index(property.id)`

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't `item` getting passed?

Comment: You should consider accepting answers that resolve the questions you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

`@item` is an instance variable, and its value is `nil` unless you set otherwise. It's what we have here - you don't set `@item` anywhere in this action, which is why it's `nil`. You should probably (assuming you have corresponding `Item` model) type:

```
@item = Item.find(params[:id])
```

before you'd like to use `@item` value.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to amend your form view to pass the `Item` id, which you can use to look up the corresponding model object in your controller:

```
%span.btn.btn-mini.btn-inverse= link_to copy_image, copy_campaign_signal_processor_item_path(@campaign, @processor, item.id) ,data: { toggle:"modal",target: "#myModal"}, remote: true
```

In your form, you're passing three arguments to your path, but you haven't named them in your route yet. You can name the parameters you'll be passing to the `copy` route within the `:items` resource block:

```
resources :items do
    member do
        get 'copy/:campaign/:processor/:item_id', :action => 'copy'
    end
end
```

Then, in your controller, you can look up your `Item` by ID:

```
def copy
   @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
   ...
end
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?